# Error: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I am trying to create a document library by sending the request to the sandbox solution. The request i am sending the request through the WebClient method listed below:

```
UploadValues(string address, string method, NameValueCollection data);
```

- where address is the url
- method is 'POST'
- data is a new NameValueCollection with JSON serialization as:

  `{"WebID":"45488d60-908f-49b7-aeed-192a71453bb2",
  "ListID":"2f571dca-a386-4f75-b412-4f7dfa041cd6",
  "DocID":-1,"DocUrl":null,"AuthorID":null,"EditorID":null,
  "DateCreated":-1,"DateModified":-1,
  "ModerationStatus":-1,
  "UpdateType":"UpdateOverwriteVersion","TaxonomyFieldsWithValue":{},"ContentType":null}`

The response I am getting from the sandbox is shown below :

Failed to update the document properties using partial trusted solution.

Error:

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields.

Server stack trace:

> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException
>   comEx)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(String strId, Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, String strViewFields,
>   Boolean bDatesInUtc, Boolean bExpandQuery)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(String strId, Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, String strViewFields,
>   Boolean bDatesInUtc)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList_SubsetProxy.GetItemById__Inner(Int32 id)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList_SubsetProxy.GetItemById(Int32 id)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> ```
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> ```
>
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList_SubsetProxy.GetItemById(Int32 id)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById__Inner(Int32 id)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(Int32 id)

Comment: Please check the names of the fields, the feel incorrect (DateCreated etc)

Comment: I have done that too but the response is same

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because in my code there was a CAML list query  referencing inexistent fields I had changed in my primary content type and in the list itself. The error stops after removing o recreating the fields again (in my case I add some code to check and avoid this error).